# Rich text in TextField and getting RenderParagraph

Tags: flutter, dart, text, richtextbox

I understand the `TextField` is primarily for plain text, but I have seen [it is possible to display richly formatted text inside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72599602/9184507). I am a beginner with Flutter though and don't quite understand what is being demonstrated. It appears that the text input is being formatted based on a RegEx as opposed to coming from data being streamed in.

I would like guidance on how to richly format text in a `TextField` and also how I can gain access to the `RenderParagraph` render object in order to compute things like text positions on the screen.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextField is primarily used for plain text input, you can achieve rich text formatting by using the TextEditingController and TextSpan classes. However, please note that formatting within a TextField might not be as versatile or as powerful as working with a widget designed specifically for rich text editing, like TextFormField combined with a SelectableText or a package like flutter_rich_text_editor

Answer (score 2):

See Flutter Textfield has a controller which is of `TextEditingController` type and it handle the inputs and can perform action accordingly to them for the `TextField`.

And In the answer you mentioned, he/she is making a custom `RichTextFieldController` that extends `TextEditingController`, enabling rich formatting within a `TextField`.

It utilizes defined patterns and associated TextStyle rules to format different parts of the input text, allowing features like @mentions, #hashtags, bold, italic, and more.

The overridden `buildTextSpan` method applies the formatting styles based on the `matched patterns`, creating a dynamic styled `TextSpan`.